# How to numbering sentences and equations in the same numbering system?

Tags: numbering

At the beginning I use `\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}` so every time I use `\begin{equation}` environment, it will tag my equations on the right with respect to sections or subsections.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\title{{\textbf{\textrm TITLE}}}
\author{Bruce}
\date{\today}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\newsavebox\thmbox
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{theorem}%
  {\begin{lrbox}{\thmbox}%
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}
   \begin{mytheorem}}%
  {\end{mytheorem}%
   \end{minipage}%
   \end{lrbox}%
   \begin{trivlist}
     \item[]\colorbox{lightgray}{\usebox\thmbox}
   \end{trivlist}}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{First Chapter}
\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{equation}
F=ma
\end{equation}
\begin{theorem}
Force is equal mass times acceleration. 
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

It will tag `F=ma` as (1.1.1).
Now I also want to number my sentence using the same numbering system, without centring the whole sentence. For example, If I use

```
\begin{equation}
\mbox{Force is equal mass times acceleration.}
\end{equation}
```

It will still number the sentence, but its output acts like an equation(centring). How can I fix that?

I try add more text in the `\theorem` environment. But the space between them are too large, or am I using the incorrect code for `flalign`?

```
\begin{theorem}
\begin{flalign}
\text{(1)Force is equal mass times acceleration.}&&
\end{flalign}
\begin{flalign}
\text{(2)Mass in conserved in general.}&&
\end{flalign}
\end{theorem}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: what do you mean by `sentence(theorem)` ? I honestly can not guess. sentences are not normally numbered in latex, and your test document has no theorems or sentences in it.

Comment: Your example just produces the error `! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 6.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
`

Comment: Sorry it should work now. I want to number my theorem 'Force is equal mass times acceleration' as (1.1.2).

Comment: Add `\numberwithin{theorem}{subsection}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Actually it is not the theorem I want to number.

Comment: @user3624246 Then what is that you want to number?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina For example, if I use '\begin{enumerate}\item Newton's First Law\item Newton's Second Law \end{enumerate}'. I want to number two laws for future referencing, not just the theorem. It's like numbering a sentence.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It should work now.

Comment: @user3624246 `! LaTeX Error: No \title given.`

Comment: In addition to the the example still generating errors your comments above mean I have no idea what output you want. I was going to answer as Gonzalo did but you say you do not want to number the theorem. If your question is about `enumerate` put an enumerate in your example and a reference to it and say _exactly_ what text you want the reference to produce

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My fault...I run it one more time and it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flalign` instead of `equation` with a double `&` at the end of the sentence:

```
\begin{flalign}
\text{Force is equal mass times acceleration.}&&
\end{flalign}
```

MWE (note the use of `\text` instead of `\mbox`)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\title{{\textbf{\textrm TITLE}}}
\author{Bruce}
\date{\today}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\newsavebox\thmbox
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{theorem}%
  {\begin{lrbox}{\thmbox}%
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}
   \begin{mytheorem}}%
  {\end{mytheorem}%
   \end{minipage}%
   \end{lrbox}%
   \begin{trivlist}
     \item[]\colorbox{lightgray}{\usebox\thmbox}
   \end{trivlist}}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{First Chapter}
\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{equation}
F=ma
\end{equation}
\begin{flalign}
\text{Force is equal mass times acceleration.}&&
\end{flalign}
\begin{theorem}
Force is equal mass times acceleration.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

### EDIT

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, maybe this?

[image]

To have that, add the following lines in your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\numleft}{\tagsleft@true}
\newcommand{\numright}{\tagsleft@false}
\makeatother
```

The first line simulates the option `leqno` of `amsmath` and the second the option `reqno`.

Use them like

```
\begin{theorem}
\numleft
\begin{flalign}
\qquad\qquad&\text{Force is equal mass times acceleration.}&\\
\qquad\qquad&\text{Force is equal mass times acceleration again.}&
\end{flalign}
\numright
\end{theorem}
```

Complete code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\title{{\textbf{\textrm TITLE}}}
\author{Bruce}
\date{\today}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\numleft}{\tagsleft@true}
\newcommand{\numright}{\tagsleft@false}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xcolor}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\newsavebox\thmbox
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{theorem}%
  {\begin{lrbox}{\thmbox}%
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}
   \begin{mytheorem}}%
  {\end{mytheorem}%
   \end{minipage}%
   \end{lrbox}%
   \begin{trivlist}
     \item[]\colorbox{lightgray}{\usebox\thmbox}
   \end{trivlist}}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{First Chapter}
\subsection{First subsection}
\begin{equation}
F=ma
\end{equation}

\begin{theorem}
\numleft
\begin{flalign}
\qquad\qquad&\text{Force is equal mass times acceleration.}&\\
\qquad\qquad&\text{Force is equal mass times acceleration again.}&
\end{flalign}
\numright
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to number them (in the front this time) under my 'theorem' environment? I tried                                 \begin{theorem}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{flalign}
\text{Force is equal mass times acceleration.}&&
\end{flalign} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}                                                     But it doesn't look nice.

Comment: @user3624246 See the edit

Comment: @user3624246 See the edit again....

Comment: @user3624246 Happy about that. Remember that you can accept the answer to mark the question as solved. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)